# StaleDataException: Access closed cursor error when rebuilding ListView

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

My app has a Listview which orders a list of Lectures. They are colour coded according to type, the custom adapter I use to do this is called by the following code -

```
cursor = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);       
startManagingCursor(cursor);
adapter = new Lectures_Adapter(this,R.layout.menu_item,cursor,FROM,TO);        
menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The code in my custom adapter is -

```
   public class Lectures_Adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
     private Context appContext;
     private int layout;
     private Cursor mycursor;

     public Lectures_Adapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,int[] to) {
          super(context, layout, c, from, to);
          this.appContext=context;
          this.layout=layout;
          this.mycursor=c;               
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)     
     {   
          View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);   
          try {             
             if (position > 0)
             {               
                RelativeLayout rowFill = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowFill);
                String title = mycursor.getString(1);                
                int myColor = 0;
                int myPos = title.indexOf("Nursing");
                int myPos2 = title.indexOf("Masterclass");
                if (myPos >= 0)
                {
                    myColor = Color.parseColor("#99FF66");
                }
                else if (myPos2  >= 0)
                {
                    myColor = Color.parseColor("#FF99FF");
                }
                else
                {
                    myColor = Color.parseColor("#FFFF66");
                }
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowFill).setBackgroundColor(myColor);                 
              }         
           }catch(Exception e) {

           }

          if (convertView == null) {
              LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.appContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              convertView = inflator.inflate(this.layout,null);
          } else {
              convertView = (View) convertView;
          }
          return view;  
      }

   }
```

I have a button which displays a Dialog box which offers the option to re-order the Listview in four different ways. When they have selected an option I re-order the Listview using the following code -

```
      Cursor newCursor = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sqlStr, null);
      adapter.changeCursor(newCursor);                  
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This all seems to work ok, except when I re-order and the above code is called, when it runs getView I get the following error 'StaleDataException: Access closed cursor'. This is apparantly because the cursor is closed, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved when you use getCursor() to grab the current cursor value.